# webresource.axd is missed in IE10

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd, internet-explorer-10

I've got the following problem. Our site on LIVE environment is not working in IE10.

Errors like: "invalid __doPostBack function" or "WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is undefined" appear.

I looked into page source and found out, that page is rendered differently. 
For example scripts with src equal to "webresource.axd..." are missing. 
Also some attributes on the form like 
onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" and onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'lbFind')" are not rendered as well.

This is reproduced only in IE10, and is working on all other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE8-IE9, etc.) On test environment our site is working in IE10. ASP.Net version is 4.0.

Could you please advice anything?

Answer (score 3):

This might help you, but it might not...  Give it a read...

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: We've implemented the methods in the above link and are still seeing the same issues, the above fix doesn't apply to every case unfortunately.

Comment: have you applied .net patches mentioned in that article?

Comment: Note that according to this link http://geekswithblogs.net/BenBarreth/archive/2012/11/30/asp.net-fails-to-detect-ie10-without-.net-hotfix.aspx you may also need to change the doctype of the pages.